# Data loading index overflow in detectron2

Tags: pytorch, artificial-intelligence, pytorch-dataloader

I use custom coco type data for training, but I encounter index overflow issues during the training process, as shown below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File ".../engine/train_loop.py", line 134, in train
        self.run_step()
      File ".../engine/defaults.py", line 429, in run_step
        self._trainer.run_step()
      File ".../engine/train_loop.py", line 222, in run_step
        data = next(self._data_loader_iter)
      File ".../data/common.py", line 179, in __iter__
        for d in self.dataset:
      File ".../python3.9/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 628, in __next__
        data = self._next_data()
      File ".../python3.9/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 1333, in _next_data
        return self._process_data(data)
      File ".../python3.9/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 1359, in _process_data
        data.reraise()
      File ".../python3.9/site-packages/torch/_utils.py", line 543, in reraise
        raise exception
    IndexError: Caught IndexError in DataLoader worker process 0.
    Original Traceback (most recent call last):
      File ".../python3.9/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/worker.py", line 302, in _worker_loop
        data = fetcher.fetch(index)
      File ".../python3.9/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 58, in fetch
        data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
      File ".../python3.9/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 58, in <listcomp>
        data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
      File ".../data/common.py", line 43, in __getitem__
        data = self._map_func(self._dataset[cur_idx])
      File ".../data/common.py", line 107, in __getitem__
        start_addr = 0 if idx == 0 else self._addr[idx - 1].item()
    IndexError: index 102724527 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 15000
```

IndexError: index 161312927 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 15000

I have traced the issue, which is caused by data index loading; But I'm not sure why this problem occurs.

This situation occurs randomly and may occur during training

Comment: any luck with that? I have similar issue